# How to calculate max value of function in range?

Tags: java

I have some function (for example, double function(double value)), and some range (for example, from A to B). I need to calculate max value of function in this range. Are there existed libraries for it? Please, give me advice.

Comment: unclear question. pls add a good problem stmt.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about `function`. For instance, what if it were a random number generator seeded by `value`?  So, are there any details of `function` that you can guarantee?

Comment: If the function is essentially a "black box" then the only way would be to check every single possible value of double. There are many existing techniques for getting an estimated maximum though, see hill climbing, various genetic algorithms, etc.

Comment: You mean, like in Mathematics when you have a function f(x) which varies depending on x and you'd like to know what is the highest value of f(x) when x is between [A;B]?

Answer (score 2):

If the function needs to handle floating-point values, you're going to have to use something like [Golden section search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search).  Note that for this specific method, there are significant limitations regarding the functions that can be handled (specifically it must be [unimodal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodal_function#Unimodal_function)).  There are some [adjustments](http://www.scribd.com/doc/126421519/Extrema) you can make to the algorithm which extend it to more functions, specifically these modifications will allow it to work for continuous functions.

Comment: I believe there is a restriction on the input (the range "A to B" that the OP mentioned).  And you are correct, the golden section search assumes unimodal function, which is why I gave the qualification in the last sentence.

Comment: The input is a double, so it's likely that x∈R and not only x∈N.

Comment: @KhoaNghiem I agree, I was just thinking that the OP could possibly change/simplify their algorithm/function to work with only integers.

Comment: Okay, I have edited the answer to address these concerns you mentioned.  Please take a look.

Comment: @NominSim BTW thanks for your feedback, but I would appreciate if we could fix the issues so the downvote can be removed.  As it stands, I feel the answer is relevant, and while it doesn't offer a full solution it certainly gives some hints to get the OP started.  The original question was pretty vague, so I felt that this amount of detail was an appropriate response.

Comment: Okay @NominSim I have incorporated these requests.  Please let me know what you think.  There is an entire book about this topic, and most (all?) of the featured algorithms are analyzed in comparison with Golden section search, so I think this is a common method for this task http://books.google.com/books?isbn=0486419983

Comment: @808sound Changed my DV to an UV. FYI, the reason I believe that most algorithms are analyzed in comparison to Golden section is that the Golden section search will result in guaranteed linear convergence. It isn't the common method to find global min/max, but given its unique properties it is a good benchmark to compare other algorithms to.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a continuous function, or a set of discrete values? If discrete values, then you can either iterate over all values, and set max/min flags as 808sound suggests, or you can load all values into an array.

If it's a continuous function, then you can either populate an array with the function's value at discrete inputs, and find the max as above, or if it's differentiable, then you can use basic calculus to find the points at which df(x)/dx are 0. The latter case is a little more abstract, and probably more complicated than you want, though?

A quick google search led me to this:
http://code.google.com/p/javacalculus/

But I've never used it myself, so I don't know if that implements the required functionality. It does differential equations, though, so I assume they'd have "baby stuff" like basic differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there are any librairies in Java for your problem.
But I know you can easily do that with MatLab (or Octave for the OpenSource equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have any indication of what the functions inner workings are (i.e. the function is a black box that accepts an input and produces an output), there is no "easy" way to find the global maximum.

There are an infinite number of points to choose for your input (technically) so "iterating over all possible inputs" is not feasible mathematically.

There are various algorithms that will give you **estimated** maximum values ina function like this:

The [hill climbing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing), and the [firefly algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_algorithm) are two, but there are many more. This is a fairly well documented/studied computer science problem and there is a lot of material online for you to look at. I suggest starting with the hill climbing algorithm, and maybe expanding out to other global optimization algorithms.

Note: *These algorithms do not guarantee that the result is the maximum, but provide an estimate of its value.**